# Integrate SoapUI tests into Team Foundation Server CI?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, soapui, tfsbuild

I have a set of tests in SoapUI, is it possible to integrate them into TFS CI?
Have anyone done this before?

Comment: Anything is possible. Do you have a specific question? See [Ask].

Answer (score 1):

With SoapUI you can call your test using a bat file. add this bat file to your source control so that it is carried accross with the build.

Add an invoke process to your build template and then call out to the SoapUI test runner.

SoapUI documantation can be found here http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html

Comment: question is how I know the result is fail or pass, and integrate in TFS build process?